# Empty columns returned and org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

Using Hibernate, I'm trying to execute the following sql command (which runs in the SQL commander of dbVisualizer)

```
select  positionreferenceedi.reference as "EDI",
position.datedepart as "datedepart", 
positionadresseenlevement.raisonsociale as "raison sociale expéditeur",
positionadresselivraison.raisonsociale as "raison sociale destinataire",
positionadresselivraison.codepostal as "code postal",
positionadresselivraison.codepostal as "ville",
position.colis+position.palette as "colis",
position.poids+position.poidspalette as "poids",
position.pointagelibelle as "Statut",
substring(text(position.pointagedate) from 1 for 10) as "Date statut",
'' as "COM.",
'' as "CODE",
'' as "RESP EXT.",
'' as "RESP ZEUS",
'' as "RESP BIDON" 
from position 
left join positionadresse positionadresseenlevement on (positionadresseenlevement.idposition = position.id and positionadresseenlevement.typeadresse=0) 
left join positionadresse positionadresselivraison on (positionadresselivraison.idposition = position.id and positionadresselivraison.typeadresse=1) 
left join positionreference positionreferenceseq on (positionreferenceseq.idposition = position.id and positionreferenceseq.typereference='seq') 
left join positionreference positionreferenceedi on (positionreferenceedi.idposition = position.id and positionreferenceedi.typereference='edi') 
left join positionreference positionreferencecab on (positionreferencecab.idposition = position.id and positionreferencecab.typereference='cab') 
left join positionreference positionreferencesst on (positionreferencesst.idposition = position.id and positionreferencesst.typereference='4edi')  
where position.id in (:list) "
```

The code :

```
String queryString=getQueryFromDB(); // The query string is saved in a PostgreSQL table

Query query = session.createSQLQuery(queryString).setParameterList("list", idPositionList);                
List list = query.list();
buildXLSFile(list);
```

Hibernates throws the following exception "org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111" on query.list() (idPositionList is a List);

If I remove the lines 
    '' as "COM.",
    '' as "CODE",
    '' as "RESP EXT.",
    '' as "RESP ZEUS",
    '' as "RESP BIDON"
then the query runs fine...

So I guess that Hibernate doesn't accept empty columns but I need to retrieve the information with empty columns (except their titles) in order to build an xls file (with those specific blank columns that users will complete later) at the end of the process.

The main idea is to build a system that every user can use to run predefined requests using ids grabbed from other requests in our SI.

Any idea to help me to achieve my goal without having to code in order to insert blank columns at the right place?

Thanks for your help!

Laurent

PS: Sorry for my english...